# Get docker overlay hash path by layer sha256

Tags: docker

Each docker image layer correlates to overlay data on disk (in case of using "overlay" engine).

I.e.
We do inspect of docker image and get it's layers:

```
docker inspect <image> | grep 'RootFS' -A5
"RootFS": {
            "Type": "layers",
            "Layers": [
                "sha256:9c2f1836d49346677f8280bf0eb89c20853f6af4aa6e2fad87b0000bb181fad2",
                "sha256:97a77835754fbd5f0883e663cd168ae6263551318d56476920ea05e500e371e6",
                "sha256:7ea85bb6d4ef6de5e5ccaf47325b770b954142666b89ab034a0dff3cb98a2808",
...
```

Layer "sha256:9c2f1836d49346677f8280bf0eb89c20853f6af4aa6e2fad87b0000bb181fad2" correlates to data on disk, for example to "/var/lib/docker/overlay/0608b16c5e9a58f48cfe30ce9559b5c8676e23655719c7141fe75ae86076c3a9/root".

Is it possible to get this docker overlay root path /var/lib/docker/overlay/{hash}/root by image layer sha256?